# How to use TinyMCE editor in symfony2 twig file with textarea

Tags: javascript, symfony, tinymce

I am not able to get TinyMCE editor into my twig file. my twig file code is as below

```
{% block content %}
    {{ tinymce_init() }}
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class="pg-title">Add emailTemplate</h2>

        <div class="specialty adProvier">
            <form action="{{ path('_admin_new_emailTemplate') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="specialtyForm" id="add-emailTemplate">

                {{ form_row(form._token) }}

                {{ form_row(form.templateKeyword) }}

                {{ form_row(form.senderEmail) }}

                {{ form_row(form.translations)}}

                {{ form_row(form.isActive) }}                

                {{ form_rest(form) }}

                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" id="save" class="button" value="Save" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancel" class="button" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/dashboardadmin/js/admin.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/stfalcontinymce/js/init.jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/stfalcontinymce/js/init.standard.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/stfalcontinymce/js/ready.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({

    selector: 'textarea',
});

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

My Form builder file has the below code:

```
$builder->add('content', 'textarea', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'label' => 'Content:',
                'class' => 'tinymce',
                'data-theme' => 'simple' // simple, advanced, bbcode
            )
        ));
```

Now my problem is that i m not able to see tinyMce editor for my Content textarea..

i m just getting a simple textarea field.

Please help me getting the tinyMCE editor

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the `{{ tinymce_init() }}` function in your Twig template (it will save you from using `{{ asset() }}`) and [configure TinyMCE with app/config/config.yml file](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle#custom-configurations). With the ".tinymce" selector and the "tinymce" class on your `<teaxtarea>`, it should work. The [TinyMCE configuration is detailed in its documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration).

I suggest you this simple configuration :

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    include_jquery: false
    tinymce_jquery: true
    selector: ".tinymce"
```

Have you checked that TinyMCE is properly installed in your bundles ? Do you see TinyMCE when running the `php app/console assets:install web --symlink` command ? Have you cleared your browser's cache ?

Comment: Hi Alexis , i used what u said but still i m not able to get tinymce editor...can u tell me what specific configurations i need to configure in config.yml file

Answer (score 1):

you are following JavaScript use  in your twig file

INCLUDE IN THIS SCRIPT `http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js`

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>

tinymce.init({
    selector: '.absurls',
    plugins: 'link image code',
    relative_urls: false
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#abshosturls',
    plugins: 'link image code',
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#relurls',
    plugins: 'link image code',
    relative_urls: true
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#relurlstopage',
    plugins: 'link image code',
    relative_urls: true,
    document_base_url: 'http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/'
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: "#nourlconvert",
    plugins: 'link image code',
    convert_urls: false
});
```